# Adding values to a hash within/over multiple each loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a concept called `snapshot` which basically stores a snapshot of how data looked at a certain period of time. What I'm building is a method that loops through the snapshots for each events, and builds a small hash outlining the ownership over time for a given shareholder.

```
  def fetch_ownership_over_time(shareholder, captable)

    @shareholder = Shareholder.find(shareholder.id)
    @captable = Captable.find(captable.id)
    @company = @captable.company.id
    @ownership_over_time = []

    @captable.events.collect(&:snapshot).each do |snapshot|
      parsed_snapshot = JSON.parse(snapshot)

      @ownership_over_time.push(parsed_snapshot["event"]["name"])
      @ownership_over_time.push(parsed_snapshot["event"]["date"])

      parsed_snapshot["shareholders"].each do |shareholder|
        if shareholder["id"] == @shareholder.id

          @ownership_over_time.push(shareholder["ownership_percentage"]) 

        end
      end
    end
    return @ownership_over_time
  end
```

I then call this method in my view which successfully retrieves the correct values however they are not structured in any way:

```
["Event 1 ", "2018-11-19", "0.666666666666667", "Event 2 ", "2018-11-19", "0.333333333333333", "4th event ", "2018-11-19", "0.315789473684211"]
```

What I'd like to do now though is construct my hash so that each separate snapshot event contains a `name`, `date` and `ownership_percentage`.

Perhaps something like this:

```
ownership_over_time = [
    {
    event_name = "Event 1" #parsed_snapshot["event"]["name"]
    event_date = "20180202" #parsed_snapshot["event"]["date"]
    ownership_percentage = 0.37 #shareholder["ownership_percentage"]
    },
    {
    event_name = "Event 2" #parsed_snapshot["event"]["name"]
    event_date = "20180501" #parsed_snapshot["event"]["date"]
    ownership_percentage = 0.60 #shareholder["ownership_percentage"]
    }
]
```

My challenge though is that the `["event"]["name"]` an `["event"]["date"]` attributes I need to fetch when looping over my snapshots i.e. the first loop (`.each do |snapshot|`) whereas I get my `ownership_percentage` when looping over shareholders  - the second loop (`.each do |shareholder|`).

So my question is - how can I build this hash in "two" places so I can return the hash with the 3 attributes?

Appreciative of guidance/help - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new hash for the object and append that hash to the array of objects you are creating.

```
  def fetch_ownership_over_time(shareholder, captable)

    @shareholder = Shareholder.find(shareholder.id)
    @captable = Captable.find(captable.id)
    @company = @captable.company.id
    @ownership_over_time = []

    @captable.events.collect(&:snapshot).each do |snapshot|
      parsed_snapshot = JSON.parse(snapshot)
      shareholder = parsed_snapshot['shareholders'].select { |s| s['id'] == @shareholder.id }.first

      local_snapshot = {
        'event_name' => parsed_snapshot['event']['name'],
        'event_date' => parsed_snapshot['event']['date'],
        'ownership_percentage' => shareholder.try(:[], "ownership_percentage") || 0
      }

      @ownership_over_time.push local_snapshot
    end
    return @ownership_over_time
  end
```

Notice that I changed your second loop to a `select`. As you currently have it, you risk on pushing two percentages if the `id` is found twice.

**EDIT:**

Added functionality to use a default value if no `shareholder` is found.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it suits your needs, perhaps there is a more efficient way to solve it or a more stylish way to write it, but I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: For sure - I've been pondering how best to solve this but will push on from here and try refactor a little. Thank you again!

Comment: One thing I've run into is that we get a crash if the ownership_percentage is null or none exist. Do you think I should just wrap the entire `local_snapshot` in an `unless not null` so that we skip creating that snapshot if so?

Comment: You can skip pushing it into `@ownership_over_time` writing this single line before it: `next if local_snapshot['ownership_percentage'].blank?`.

Comment: Or you could give a default value for it when creating the `local_snapshot`. As it is a percentage, a persona having 0 is probably what you want when none is found: `'ownership_percentage' => shareholder['ownership_percentage'] || 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184100/discussion-between-jp89-and-byrdemmanuel).